# print data using ireport 3.7.6 according to following format in primefaces

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using `jasper ireport 3.7.6` in `primefaces`. I have to print seat plan of students for different classes.for each class there is hierarchy of subjects and I have to print the list of students in those classes by displaying the subject name according to the hierarchy followed by list of students giving that exam. The print format is as follows:

[image]

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related?

Comment: Whats your question at all?